# Sprites that are partially off screen

Tags: html, html5-canvas, sprite, createjs, easeljs

I have a sprite 300x200px and when it is partially off the screen, it starts appearing on the left side (like a cycled sides). Hidden area becomes visible on the left side.

How to avoid that?

```
    var ss = queue.getResult(spriteName);
    ss.images = [queue.getResult(spriteName + "_png")];

    var ssheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(ss);  
    var sprite = new createjs.Sprite(ssheet);

    sprite.gotoAndPlay("ssh");
    sprite.x = 550;
    stage.addChild(sprite);
```

Update (to be more clear):

Stage is 640x480 in size; Sprite is on the right side of the stage and 30% of the sprite is hidden because its off screen. For some reason this 30% of hidden sprite are being shown and played on the left side of the stage. It looks like a cycled tube. Hidden part are immediately shown on the other side of the stage.

Comment: Consider showing some code

Comment: If your sprite is "wrapping" in its bounds, then the bounds are not set right.

Comment: That is by design, I want my game character be hidden on 30% off the right stage bound. And then it appear in full. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: Lanny, I got you now. No, it is not wrapping bounds problem. I've just undestood what you meant. Frames' borders are definitely correct in the spritesheet. Otherwise I would get that wrapping problem regardless of the sprite position on the stage. Current problem appears ONLY if part of the sprite is off stage (off right screen border in my case).

Comment: Are you saying the sprite wraps on the actual stage? There is nothing in EaselJS that would do that automatically...

Comment: Yes, it wraps right on the stage and it starts to load CPU actively (it can be noticed on the desktop as well).